# writing down the minimal discriminant of an elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $j$ be an integer.

Does there exist an elliptic curve $E_j$ over $\mathbf{Q}$ with $j$-invariant equal to $j$ whose minimal discriminant we can write down in a practical way?

For example, can we write down an elliptic curve $E_j$ as above for which we know the reduction over $\mathbf{Z}$ and we know a number field $K$ such that $E_j$ obtains semi-stable reduction over $K$.

Comment: For a give $j\in\mathbb Z$, there is not a unique $E$ over $\mathbb Q$ with $j$ as $j$-invariant. So you formulate differently your question.

Comment: I forgot that every twist of an elliptic curve has the same j-invariant. I accordingly changed the formulation of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "practical way" you mean a fast algorithm, I think that's possible.
 In $char \neq 2,3$
$$j=1728 \frac{c_4^3}{c_4^3-c_6^2}$$
(see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant#Algebraic_definition )
Therefore given a $j$-invariant we can solve for $c_4$ and $c_6$, and if they can be chosen to be rational, we already have a curve $E$ over $\mathbb Q$ to start with. I assume for convenience that $j \neq 0,1728$.

Given $E$, we can use the process Stein and Watkins applied to construct their table, see http://modular.math.washington.edu/papers/stein-watkins/

The relevant part is

> For each
>   $(c_4 , c_6 )$ pair (again with $c_4 \le 1.44 \cdot 10^{12}$ ) which satisfies the $|\Delta| \le 10^{12}$
>   condition, we then determine whether this curve is minimal —not only
>   in the traditional sense for its minimal discriminant, but also whether
>   it is has the minimal discriminant in its family of quadratic twists. For
>   $p \ge 5$, this is rather easy to determine; unless $p^6 | \Delta$ and $p | c_4$, the curve
>   is minimal for quadratic twists (the only difference between this and the
>   standard notion of minimality is that the exponent here is 6 instead of 12).
>   If both the above conditions hold, then we throw the curve out, as $E_\tilde{p}$
>   where $\tilde{p} = \left( \frac{-1}{p} \right)p$, is a curve with lesser discriminant.

Here $E_\tilde{p}$ refers to the quadratic twist by $\tilde{p}$. It appears to me you could twist by $\tilde{p}$ and repeat this process until you arrive at a twist of minimal conductor (apart from $2,3$), then you can find its minimal discriminant.

For $2$ and $3$ there are possibly more complications, but you can just do trial and error among the finitely many possible twists.

p.s. When $E$ has nontrivial $p$-torsion over a number field $K$, reduction at all places of $K$ not lying over $p$ must be semistable. (e.g. see the paper "Abelian varieties having purely additive reduction")
You can construct many fields this way where the curve becomes semistable.